# Mixed beta regression interpretation with categorical predictor

Tags: regression, odds-ratio, beta-distribution, lsmeans

I have run mixed beta regressions on proportional data but I am struggling in my interpretation of the results. I understand this has been asked before but I have a categorical predictor with four levels and I want to understand exactly what my results mean.

In my example I have the proportion of particulate matter found in a sample within four different locations. I have 'site' as a random factor. I have used glmmTMB with beta_family.

```
CPOMmod2 <- glmmTMB(proportion ~ feature + (1|site), REML = TRUE, family = beta_family, data = cpomfilter)
```

I believe the model coefficients are log-odds and the exponent of these coefficients are odd-ratios. The plot below shows the odds ratios from the plot_model function (sjPlot).

My question is, is the interpretation of these results that "the odds of there being a higher proportion of particulate matter in Loc3 compared to Loc0 (the baseline) increased by 1.5 times (however, CIs were just overlapping)"?

Furthermore, is there a way to use emmeans (or another package) to get marginal means from a beta regression (I seem to get the log-odds)?

```
    <      Family: beta  ( logit )
Formula:          proportion ~ feature + (1 | site)
Data: cpomfilter

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  -877.7   -861.4    444.9   -889.7      110 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev. 
 site   (Intercept) 1.8e-09  4.243e-05
Number of obs: 112, groups:  site, 8

Dispersion parameter for beta family (): 49.2 

Conditional model:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -4.74940    0.19507 -24.347   <2e-16 ***
featureLoc1 -0.02975    0.23711  -0.125    0.900    
featureLoc2  0.08328    0.21931   0.380    0.704    
featureLoc3  0.41225    0.29055   1.419    0.156
```

[image]

Comment: See the [answer I *just* posted](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/626866/how-to-compute-mean-ratios-and-their-95-confidence-intervals-in-a-bayesian-mode) to a similar question

Comment: Thanks Russ Lenth